# @Ngrx/store: how to query models with relationships

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I an Angular 2 app using Redux (with @ngrx/store), I have modeled the store this way:

```
{

  modelA: {
    ids: [1, 2],
    entities: { 1: { name: "name modelA 1" },
                2: { name: "name modelA 2" }
              }
  },

  modelB: {
    ids: [5, 8],
    entities: { 5: { name: "name modelB 5" },
                8: { name: "name modelA 8" },
                9: { name: "name modelA 9" }
              }
  } 

}
```

Basically, I have 2 types of objects: modelA and modelB. This is ok for now.
But I can't find which is the best way to write a relationship between then, representing something like modelA has many modelB (one-to-many). Can I do something like this?

```
modelAmodelB: {
  entities: {
    1: [5],
    2: [8, 9]
  }
}
```

This is in the root of the store, it's not a child from 'modelA'.
This might work, but how then would I 'query' the modelB from a specific modelA, using @ngrx/store methods? Because if I write a selector function that reads the global state and returns the partial state from modelAmodelB, I don't have access to the rest of the state when I compose my functions. Example:

```
compose(getModelAEntities(number[]), getModelAModelBRelations(modelA_id: number), getModelAModelBState() );
```

I can query this using Observable.combineLast

```
Observable
.combineLatest(
  this.store.select('contentContents'),
  this.store.select('contents'),
  (relations: any, contents: any) => {
    return relations.entities[1].map( id => {
      return contents.entities[id]
    })
  }
).subscribe( data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

But I don't know if this is right: anytime I change modelA entities object (adding a new one, for example), the subscribe() is called, but the output is the same, because neither modelA entity has changed nor its modelB related objects.

PS: I could do the query this way

```
export const getModelAModelBs = (id) => {
  return state => 
    state.select( (s: any) => [s.modelAModelB.entities[id], s.modelB.entities])
    .distinctUntilChanged( (prev, next) => {

      const new_m = (next[0] || []).map( id => {
        return next[1][id];
      });

      const old_m = (next[0] || []).map( id => {
        return prev[1][id];
      });

      return prev[0] === next[0] && (JSON.stringify(new_m) === JSON.stringify(old_m))
    })
    .map( ([ids = [], modelBs]) => ids.map( id => modelBs[id]) );
};

//use the selector
this.store.let(getModelAModelBs(1)).subscribe( data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

But I don't know if this is the best approach.

Comment: You can read this article - https://netbasal.com/querying-a-normalized-state-with-rxjs-in-angular-71ecd7ca25b4

Comment: if you want a practical example, you should take a look into [Pizza-Sync](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync). And there's this [file](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/3a354c58d621fa7135f79acd5b611a2b06116d7a/frontend/src/app/shared/states/pizzas-categories/pizzas-categories.selector.ts) that might interest you in particular.

Comment: try using switchMap on first select then on the basis on first data you can query other select for your relation then return the select and you will get the value.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same issue and came up with a solution of wrappers.

Please take a look at the `ngrx-entity-relationship` library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-entity-relationship

you can create selectors like that:

```js
export const selectUserWithCompany = entityUser(
  entityUserCompany(),
);
```

and then to use it with the store

```js
this.store.select(selectUserWithCompany, 'userId');
```

to get

```js
{
  id: 'userId',
  companyId: 'companyId',
  company: {
    id: 'companyId',
    // ...,
  },
  // ...,
}
```