# ngrx selecting data of specific object id with memoization method

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

my question is regarding ngrx4 (with angular5).

i am working on an app with the following data structure:

```
-> store
--> forums: id, name
--> posts: id, message, forumid
```

when i present a post, i also present it's forum. so a post representation would be:

> postid, message, forum.id, forum.name

from ngrx example app i understand that the way to get forum's data is to:

1. add selectedForumId to the forum state
2. when fetching a post: dispatch event to update selectedForumId to the post's forumid
3. select forum data by selectedForumId

in code:

home.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new postActions.GetAllPostsAction());
    this.posts$ = store.select(fromReducers.getAllPosts);
  }
```

home.component.html:

```
<post *ngFor="let post of (posts$|async)" [post]="post"></post>
```

post.component.ts:

```
  @Input() post: Post;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new forumActions.SelectForumAction(this.post.forumId));
    this.forum$ = this.store.select(fromReducers.getSelectedForum);
  }
```

forum.reducer.ts:

```
export interface State extends EntityState<Forum> {
    selectedForumId: number | null;
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: ForumActions): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ForumActionTypes.SELECT_FORUM:
            return {
                ...state,
                selectedForumId: action.payload,
            };
...
export const getSelectedForumId = (state: State) => state.selectedForumId;
```

reducers/index.ts:

```
export const selectForumState = createFeatureSelector<fromForum.State>('forums');
export const selectForumEntities = createSelector(selectForumState, fromForum.selectForumEntities);
export const selectedForumId = createSelector(selectForumState, fromForum.getSelectedForumId);
export const getSelectedForum = createSelector<State, any, any, Forum>(selectForumEntities, selectedForumId,
    (entities, id) => entities[id]
);
```

**The Question -**

my problem with this a approach is that if i have 10 posts in a page it means i would dispatch the action that updates selectedForumId 10 times and it feels wrong.

is there a better-practice approach i can use, that will still use the advantage of createSelector which creates a memoized selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) in my example i did some bad practice when i fetched data from my store inside what's supposed to be a dumb component (post.component.ts)

2) **first solution**

at first i came with this question:
[@Ngrx/store: how to query models with relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327028/ngrx-store-how-to-query-models-with-relationships)

where in the comments was a link to the following article: https://netbasal.com/querying-a-normalized-state-with-rxjs-in-angular-71ecd7ca25b4

this article brought me to implement the solution:

posts.service.ts:

```
getPostsViewModel(posts$: Observable<Post[]>, users$: Observable<User[]>, forums$: Observable<Forum[]>): Observable<PostView[]> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(posts$, users$, forums$, (posts, users, forums) => {
        return posts.map(post => Object.assign({}, post, {
            user: users.find(user => user.id === post.userId),
            forum: forums.find(forum => forum.id === post.forumId)
        }))
    });
}
```

home.component.ts:

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new postActions.GetAllPostsAction());

    this.postsView$ = this.postService.getPostsViewModel(
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getAllPosts),
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getAllUsers),
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getAllForums));
   }
```

and this solutions works!

3) **second solution**

but i was still bothered that i didnt use the createSelector memoization abilities. so armed with this new approach i tried to think how this can be applied into createSelector, and here is the answer:

reducers/index.ts:

```
export const selectPostIds = createSelector(selectPostState, fromPost.selectPostIds);
export const selectPostEntities = createSelector(selectPostState, fromPost.selectPostEntities);
export const selectedForumId = createSelector(selectForumState, fromForum.getSelectedForumId);
export const getAllUsers = createSelector<State, any, any, User[]>(selectUserEntities, selectUserIds,
    (entities, ids) => ids.map(id => entities[id])
);
export const getAllForums = createSelector<State, any, any, Forum[]>(selectForumEntities, selectForumIds,
    (entities, ids) => ids.map(id => entities[id])
);

export const getAllPosts = createSelector<State, any, any, any, any, PostView[]>(selectPostEntities, selectPostIds, getAllUsers, getAllForums,
    (entities, ids, users, forums) => {
        let posts = ids.map(id => entities[id]);
        return posts.map(post => Object.assign({}, post, {
            user: users.find(user => user.id === post.userId),
            forum: forums.find(forum => forum.id === post.forumId)
        }));
    }
);
```

home.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new postActions.GetAllPostsAction());
    this.posts$ = this.store.select(fromReducers.getAllPosts);
  }
```

and now i have the solution in createSelector()!

**i still wonder though -**

is the memoization process in my implementation is good enough?

wouldnt it be better to create a method called:

getForumFromListOfForums(forums:Forum[], forumId)

and use loadsh to memoize it?

then go to it from the post.component.ts and let each post ask for its forum?

that way if a forum was already asked before the response is memoized and therefore would be O(1).

Comment: Instead of getting users and forums in as an array to getAllPosts you could speed up immensely by getting those in as entity hashes. Lookup wouldn't have to loop every use and every forum instead just check like userEntities[post.userId]